# How do I identify if an email address is already used as an Apple ID?

Tags: email, apple-id

My wife needs her own Apple ID, so I went to this webapp, which Apple has designed to let you know if you already have an Apple ID associated with your email:

https://iforgot.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSiForgot.woa/wa/findYourAppleID

It said my wife's email address was not associated with an Apple ID.  Great!  So I went to this webapp to create her ID:

https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/103/wa/createAppleId/

But after I entered her email (and other info), it said this email was already in use or associated with an Apple ID.

So which is it?  Does she have an Apple ID or not?  If not, how can I find out how Apple is already using this email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to have more than 1 email account associated with an Apple ID, without the 2nd address actually being one.  So for example while my Apple ID is from a personal domain, say xyz@1234.com, I also have an icloud email address xyz123@me.com that is associated with my Apple ID.  If your wide used a mobile me account, maybe as part of a family pack, and you migrated it to icloud, it's possible that it has gained such a link in some way.

Comment: How do I find out?  And if I have a link, how do I unlink it?

Comment: Try the suggestion from Erpheus, attempt a password reset.  It would be useful to know the domain names of the emails in questions, if they are not me.com or mac.com, then my answer is not applicable.

Comment: Turns out your answer is applicable after all.  I found that her email was a secondary email on my Apple ID.  When I removed it, Bingo!  I could use it to create a new Apple ID.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest trying the forgot password link: https://iforgot.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSiForgot.woa/wa/iforgot?language=NZ-EN&app_id=93&s=523-523

If it doesn't work you should probably contact iTunes support

Comment: Good idea, and I've already tried this.  She never gets an email from Apple.

Comment: Apparently this webapp does not works if the email is only associated with another Apple ID.